# Read json values from curl GET response

Tags: bash

How can I get a specific field from the json response?

```
#!/bin/bash -
status=`curl -sk -H "api-token: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://path_to/values`
```

The response is

```
{
  "cancelled": false,
  "percentage": 0.5,
  "state": "running"
}
```

I want to poll the 'status' that the response percentage is 100 and the cancelled field is always true. Can this be done without another tool like jq?

EDIT

I`m trying to figure out if I can install jq on the system. Is my approach correct using jq?

```
while
   update_status=`curl -sk -H "api-token: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://path_to/values`
   cancelled=$(jq -r '.cancelled' <<< "$update_status")
   percentage_complete=$(jq -r '.percentage_complete' <<< "$update_status")
   state=$(jq -r '.state' <<< "$update_status")
   [[ $cancelled -eq 1 || $state == 'running' ]]
do true; done
```

"cancelled" is a boolean and "state" is a string with the values "running" or "not_running".
How can I add a log message which shows if the update fails or not? I`m not pretty sure with the do while loop...

```
echo "[INFO] Update done" ## depending on the failed var?
```

Comment: *"Can this be done without another tool like jq?"* -- there are also other programs that can handle JSON. It probably does not matter which one you use, just pick one and use it. Do not attempt to do JSON parsing using `sed` or `awk` or other tool that is not specifically designed to work with JSON.

Comment: Using `jq`, getting any value from the response is as easy as `echo "$status" | jq -r .cancelled` (it outputs `false`).

Answer (score 0):

Using jq and reading the results into an array:

```
readarray -t dat <<< "$(curl -sk -H "api-token: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://path_to/values | jq -r '.cancelled,.percentage,.state')"
```

The array can then be used in an if statement:

```
if [[ "${dat[0]" == "true" && "${dat[1]" == "100" ]]
then
     echo "There are no issues"
else
     echo "There are issues"
fi
```

If jq is really not an option and if the json returned is as posted, you can use awk and return back an error code:

```
if (curl -sk -H "api-token: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://path_to/values | awk '/(cancelled)|(percentage)|(state)/ { gsub("[\",:]","",$0);gsub(" ","",$1);map[$1]=$2 } END { if ( map["cancelled"]=="false" && map["percentage"] == 100 ) { exit 0 } else { exit 1 } }');
then
     echo "There are no issues"
else
     echo "There are issues"
fi
```

Pipe the output of the curl command into awk and where there is "cancelled", "percentage" or "state" in the line, process. Remove any "," or double quotes or ":" from the line and then remove any spaces from the first space delimited field with gsub and then add to an array called map and use the first field as the index and the second field as the value. At the end, check the indexes of the map array and exit with 0 if all are as expected, otherwise, exit with 0.

Comment: I'd rather suggest calling `python` or whatever other tool that better handles JSON than attempting to parse it as a simple string.